# Mount SMB on boot

Tags: centos, mount, smb

I have a NAS share mounted in CentOS7 through SMB. I did this with:

```
sudo mount.cifs //10.23.83.7/Videos /mnt/smb/plex -o user=plex
```

This is clearly for a Plex Media Server, but when I reboot it is no longer mounted. How can I:

- Have it auto mount on boot
- Include the password in the cmd so that I don't have to enter it. Security of that password is not a concern.

Comment: Look at ```man fstab```.